# Under what conditions is $\sin x\sin(x+y)$ positive for $x \in [0,\pi/2]$ and $y \in [0,\pi]$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Given the following relation between two angles $x$ and $y$:
> $$f=\sin x\sin(x+y)$$
> so that $x \in [0,\pi/2]$ and $y \in [0,\pi]$. What are the conditions so that this function is always positive?

It has two possible ways, either both $sines$ are positive or both negative. I got lost how to do that. I tried to simplify this function using:
$$\sin a\sin b=\frac{1}{2}[\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)]$$
which means we need to think about that sign of $\cos x - \cos(2x+y)$. Any suggestions?

Comment: $\sin x \geq 0$ for all $x \in [0,\frac {\pi} 2]$. If $y \in [0,\frac {\pi} 2]$ then $f \geq 0$.

Comment: Note that for $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ we have $\sin{x} \geq 0$. So the only case is $\sin(x + y) \geq 0$. For what values of $0 \leq x + y \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\sin(x + y)$ is non-negative?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio, it's just when you come from non-mathematical background and go stuck. I was not sure about different things. For example, what if $x$ has a negative sense of direction and $y$ has a positive sense of direction. How that will affect on the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of tangent, sine and cosine are non-negative from $[0,\pi/2]$ then only sine, only tangent, and only cosine in the next three quadrants, so sine is non-negative for $x$ in $[0,\pi]$.

Didn't your teacher give you some mnemonic to remember "All, Sine, Tangent, Cosine"?

> $$f=\sin x\sin(x+y)$$

> so that $x \in [0,\pi/2]$ and $y \in [0,\pi]$

Then $\sin x$ is always non-negative and $\sin(x+y)$ is positive as long as $0 < x+y <\pi$. It is zero at $\pi$ and then negative for $\pi < x \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$. Therefore, the desired conditions are $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $x + y \in (0, \pi)$.

Comment: What in case was x and y of opposite directions i.e. $x \in [0,\pi/2]$ and $y \in[-\pi,0]$

Comment: Why are you asking me that in the comment?

Comment: Well, it was just a wondering while reading comments and answers. thanks anyway